# Pushing HTML to a web page (JS VS PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, performance

I was just curious about the title because I have been using PHP to load up my search results with HTML, and now I have started to use javascript for this purpose.

Previously I was doing the following on my website to load search results on a page

```
<?php
//example code
echo ' <div class = "container">
<div class = "box"> <p> Searh result e.g foo bar </p> </div>
 </div>'

?>
```

Now the above would work when I called an ajax function to post the search text to the PHP page, and the page would return all the matched results along with HTML, and the jQuery would push the result on my page

What I am doing right now is I am posting the search text via ajax to a PHP page  but this time instead of returning all the search results packed in HTML tags, it return a JSON type array with only data in it

Now when I receive this data array from PHP I send it to a custom (self-made) javascript function that iterates through the array and generates the HTML as following (e.g.)

```
 for (myData in data) 
    {
            results+='<li>'+
                '<div class="row">'+
                    '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 no-margin">'+
                        '<a href="">'+data[myData].name+'</a>'+
                        '<div class="price">'+
                            '<div class="">'+data[myData].price+'</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
            '</li>';
    }
```

In the end, the variable `results` has all the HTML along with data which is then pushed to the page via jQuery append.

So in the first method all the work is being done on the server side and it is returning a huge amount of data because of the HTML tags which will be multiplied by the number of results returned

While in the second method the server will only return a JSON type array of data
and the rest of work will be done on the client side. So The question is, Is the second method better than the first one in any way or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Besides the traffic I would say maintainability might be an issue - but this depends on the technology you focussed on.

Comment: second is better, as you don't have to pass too much data from server to client, just send `json` and do tricks on other end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches are equally valid, but there are a couple things to consider for each approach:

## PHP

- It works even if the user has JavaScript disabled

## JavaScript

- Processing is offloaded to the client, putting less load on your servers.

  - The actual amount of load is going to be negligible since the only "processing" is building HTML
- Less traffic, but if your server is compressing the response (it likely is), then this isn't really a noticeable difference.
- Faster, more responsive page if you're using ajax, since it doesn't have to reload the entire page.
- Doesn't work if the user has JavaScript disabled.

In the end, I'd go with JavaScript unless you know you have a lot of users who disable it.

Ideally you would have a no-JS fallback where PHP creates the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

When you're talking about small simple website, do what you like...

When it comes to more complex applications you **must** to separate your data from presentation. So the right way, I think, will be to use templates at first.

Then, you can choose the side:

**Client side** will be better, when using some framework or your application *HTML* changes instantly. You get the data you need and render it on client. Using template engine.

**Server side** may be good if you need to build large amount of *HTML* with some difficult logic and need it once or twice...

Also you can use the same template engine for both sides, so you can combine.

I think, it's always about the combination of ways, so prepare your app for both.
(Maybe designing from the start for *REST*)

P.S. It may help: [Sharing Templates Between PHP and JavaScript](http://www.sitepoint.com/sharing-templates-between-php-and-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer... but they're both pretty bad :-/ Why not look at something like Knockout.js. You could just update your view model with the "json type array with only data in it" and you're view updates as if like magic ;-)

Just sayin!